# How to interchange between 2 logos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```js
var logo1 = "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0816/3411/t/3/assets/logo_2x.png";
var logo2 = "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0816/3411/t/3/assets/logo_hover_2x.png";
var images = new Array (logo1, logo2);
var index = 1;

function rotateImage()
{
  $('.logoimage').fadeOut('fast', function()
  {
    $(this).attr('src', images[index]);

    $(this).fadeIn('fast', function()
    {
      if (index == images.length-1)
      {
        index = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        index++;
      }
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);
});
var images = new Array (logo2);
var index = 1;

function rotateImage()
{
  $('.logoimage').fadeOut('fast', function()
  {
    $(this).attr('src', images[index]);

    $(this).fadeIn('fast', function()
    {
      if (index == images.length-1)
      {
        index = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        index++;
      }
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);
});
```

Its working well apart from the following bugs:
Image loads even though image already is showing on page.
I have an image onmousehover effect on that image and its causing bad effect.

Is it possible to interchange between the image src and the img onmousehover src?
Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the `src` of the img tag using JavaScript as below,

```
function hover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', '//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0816/3411/t/3/assets/logo_2x.png');
}
function unhover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', '//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0816/3411/t/3/assets/logo_hover_2x.png');
}
```

and the html be

```
<img id="my-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" />
```

**After Edit :**

If you want to change it on some `timeout`, You need to put your below code inside `window.onload = function() {}`

```
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "logo_1.png";
images[1] = "logo_2.png";

var images = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    images.push("logo_" + i + ".png");
  }
  var x = 0;

function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById('ad').src = images[x];
    if (x < 8) {
      x += 1;
    } else {
      x = 0;
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', changeImg, false);
}
function changeImg() {
      var x = 0;
      setInterval(function() {
        changeImage()
      },5000);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<img id="ad" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0816/3411/t/3/assets/logo_2x.png" />
```

Comment: What i am trying to do is interchange between these images after a delay, i dont want to reload them tho

Comment: You can suggest better way to achieve same.. it will be welcomed :) @SavenzSavisaarKulbach, modifying anwer for that!

Comment: I am not sure if i am unclear but i am trying to rotate this images on a delay of like 10 seconds

Comment: The script i have now is working but on the first load, it loads the images as new which is not what i want. is it possible to select the images that are already loaded

Comment: buddy, please be clear with your requirement and mention clearly in question, and for now it is the proper solution so far

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `window.onload` when you have jQuery available.

Comment: @DavidG if Vikrant doesn't want to use jQuery - it is his choice. But then it is time for `.addEventListener()` (ignoring old IE), not for `.onload`.

Comment: welcome all suggestions and tried to help with code i tried previously

Comment: Well this one seems to do it, just it reloads the images. I placed the code to the footer to run later on load, seems to be working a little better. Still didnt find full solution tho, but im still learning XD

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to run code when hovering in or out of an element. Also use setTimeout to run code after a delay.

```js
var logo1 = "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0816/3411/t/3/assets/logo_2x.png";
var logo2 = "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0816/3411/t/3/assets/logo_hover_2x.png";

$(function() {
    $('.logoimage').hover(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.logoimage').attr('src', logo2);
        }, 1000);
    }, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.logoimage').attr('src', logo1);
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="logoimage" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0816/3411/t/3/assets/logo_2x.png">
```

Comment: can you make a rule where if image is already displaying then display the other image instead?